# How to create a metered subscription/subscription item that auto increments usage by the hour Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on a SAAS application where I charge per hour usage for a service. When a customer starts a service, the customer is charged for each hour that the service is running.

After I subscribe the customer to a product and create subscription item, I need to programmatically increment the usage of a subscription item every hour. This creates an issue because I need to create a dedicated service to read from a database, increment each subscription each hour and deal with too much overhead.

I want to be able to set the subscription item to auto increment until stop and reset itself when the billing threshold is reached.  Is there a way to auto increment a subscription item until I set it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

Billing by the hour does not mean the same as adding to the invoice every hour. You could  track how many hours the user used on your service and add the total amoun to stripe once a day, once a week, once a month.